# Size of face spots when in edit mode

Tags: customization

is there a way to change the dimension of the spots on faces when in edit mode? At the moment they are far too small and almost invisible. It is something I did on B 2.79, but now i cannot find a way for on 2.80.[image]

Comment: Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D View > Face Dot size. Note that in 2.80 the face dots only show in wireframe .

Answer (score 1):

It is available under theme settings in the user preferences
Open *Edit > User Preferences > Themes > 3D View* towards the bottom look for *Face Dot Size*

[image]